# How does this int setting syntax work?

Tags: c#

I ran into this line of code:

```
int selectedIndex = 0, itemIndex;
```

where `itemIndex` is also an integer. What does this mean?

Comment: it means `int selectedIndex = 0; int itemIndex;`

Comment: That's just defining two integer variables, but initializing just the first.

Comment: this means `selectedIndex` is set to 0 and `itemIndex` uses default value which for integer is also 0

Comment: I don't think that so if the right platform for such a question. google would be better suited

Comment: It's no an _"int setting"_. It works with every type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first specify the datatype and after that define multiple variables without specifying the datatype again by just separating them with a comma.

That means

```
int selectedIndex = 0, itemIndex;
```

is equivalent to

```
int selectedIndex = 0;
int itemIndex;
```

You could also do

```
int selectedIndex = 0, itemIndex = 9;
```

It just saves you the "int". It's common across several languages.